# Can't read url as JSON data

Tags: html, json, angular

I have this JSON data and I'm getting it's output to a html file using angular. I use a service to get JSON data and a component to create the template. After using the template, I'm getting only id value and name value, but not url value.

JSON:

```
{
 "A":1,
 "B":[
  {
   "id":1, 
   "name":"One", 
   "url":"http://myapp/rootpath/first"
  },
  {
   "id":2, 
   "name":"two", 
   "url":"http://myapp/rootpath/second"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm taking the JSON data to postArray variable in the component and pass it to the html file.

search.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {JsoncallItem} from "./jsoncall-item";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private postsURL ="http://myapp/items";

  constructor(private http: Http ) {}
 getPosts(): Observable<JsoncallItem[]>{
    return this.http
     .get(this.postsURL)
     .map((response: Response)=> {
       return <JsoncallItem[]>response.json();
     })
     .catch(this.handleError);
 }

 private handleError(error: Response) {
   return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
 }
}
```

search.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from "./../search.service";
import { JsoncallItem } from "./../jsoncall-item";
import { error } from 'util';
import { SearchtermPipe } from './../searchterm.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'app';

    _postsArray: JsoncallItem[];

  constructor(private apiSerivce: ApiService){}

  getPosts(): void {
    this.apiSerivce.getPosts().
    subscribe(
       resultArray => this._postsArray = resultArray
       )
       //error => console.log("Error :: " + error ))
  }
  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getPosts();
  }
}
```

search.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let post of _postsArray | searchterm: value">
            <a href="" id="allitem">{{post.id}}, {{post.name}}, {{post.url}}</a>
            <hr>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Output shows the id and name of each data, but not showing the url. What could be the wrong here?

Comment: The JSON in your question above is not an array, yet your response type is `Observable<JsoncallItem[]>`. Can you please provide the actual JSON that is coming back? You can check the browser developer tools in the network panel to make sure it's correct.

Comment: I made a serch list. So when I type "O" in input field, im getting 1, "One",  without getting url.
Console is not showing any error as well.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you add the JSON you're getting back from the server please? So the URL is not coming back from the server?

Comment: you mean the actual JSON? yes I mentioned it at the very beginning. I'm using that JSON object to test the functionalities of my search and hope to update it with original data laterly which are not collected yet.

Comment: With the information you've given, I cannot reproduce the issue. Please create a Stackblitz that reproduces the issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzue8a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: stackblitz show the url. But I'm still not getting it in my browser

Comment: Without the information to reproduce the issue, it's impossible to help

Comment: use HttpClient not the old and DEPRECATED http

Comment: Eliseo: Replaced http with HttpClient, but problem is still there